# Unable to recover account after suspension period

Tags: support, accounts, deleted-users, account-suspension

Almost two weeks ago, my SO account was suspended because someone up-voted my questions or answers (about which I know nothing). Up on suspension, I was logged-out automatically. When I login again, I think, I logged in as a new user, my question, answers and reputation were not there, though my profile information was still there. I also observed that my user id was different.

There was a message on profile page that account is suspended, till 10th April. Now 10th April has passed and message is gone, but still questions and answers are not showing, so does the reputation, it is currently 101. My other linked Stack Exchange accounts are normal and were never suspended.

I do not understand what happened here. Can anyone help me understand this.

**Update**

Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36119323/release-build-crashlytics-is-not-sending-line-number-in-crashreport/36119351#36119351) of, one of my answers on SO

Comment: Do any of your questions and answers show as being recently deleted or are they just gone?

Comment: On the "questions" tab on your profile page, at the bottom, there is a link "deleted recent questions".  Similarly there is one for answers on the "answers" tab. You can see deleted posts there. A deleted post should also show why it is deleted.

Comment: Questions and Answer are not showing in my profile, but accessible like this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36119351/9557215. The user of answer is disabled (not clickable), that how i figured that i have a different account now

Comment: Use the [Contact Us](https://stackoverflow.com/company/contact) link at the bottom of the page. That account on the answer you link is nuked so I doubt you'll get it back but that is something between you and SE staff to sort out. Nothing we can do for you.

Comment: @rene I have contacted SO but no answer in 2 days

Comment: They don't have an SLA, give it 6 to 8 days.

Comment: Hopefully it wasn't a horrible accident, but I very much doubt they nuked your account simply for being the target of a couple serial votes...

Comment: [The few posts I could find for your account](https://www.google.es/search?client=firefox-b&dcr=0&ei=dGvPWtSEBYvykwXGrbmwAw&q=user4774371+site%3Astackoverflow.com&oq=user4774371+site%3Astackoverflow.com&gs_l=psy-ab.3...10072.14606.0.14850.27.24.3.0.0.0.154.1690.23j1.24.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.VDzDSmYNFEg) do not look particularly spammy or problematic. Just use the contact form and explain your situation. Good luck.

Comment: @yivi should i delete this post on meta? or will it be helpful

Comment: As you wish. You can leave it up in case a moderator wants to weight in, but I'm not sure they'll even have access to your now-nuked account details. It's up to you, really.

Comment: But... You had years of contributions to the site. Sad, really. :(

Answer (score 20):

Your account came to our attention because there was clear evidence you were using a sock puppet to vote for it. When the moderator handling the case investigated, they found that your account here was one of at least a couple accounts that you had created to evade system-imposed question asking limits.

This evidence was presented to a Stack Overflow employee, who agreed that you had multiple accounts. They deleted this account and did so in a way that automatically locked out its credentials for a week.

The account was suspended before deletion because certain account types can't be automatically deleted by moderators and require manual employee review. In those cases, the account is locked via suspension until the review can take place, at which point the account is deleted or the suspension lifted.

You can contact the company directly and see if they'll go through the effort of restoring your posts to this account, but given the evidence I see here I think that will be unlikely. From what I can see, I agree with the assessment of the moderator and employee involved.

Comment: Why delete the account and ban it for a week though?  Now, since there account was deleted, they can keep asking questions after just a week (rather than six months), even though they were question banned.  You've just removed the rate limit that they had imposed on themselves for them.

Comment: @Servy - For persistent or obvious ban-evasion accounts, we've taken to using a harder deletion to prevent immediate recreation and reuse of the accounts. Not only does it automatically suspend the account for 7 days (or longer) on attempted recreation with the same credentials, it builds a temporary block against any new posts from a location for a duration. I mention it briefly [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295429/streamlining-deletion-of-quality-block-evasion-accounts), but we've found that to be a good way to escalate things beyond the standard anti-recidivism measures.

Comment: So it's nice that those mechanisms are harder to subvert, but the problem is that the restrictions themselves are *dramatically* less restrictive.  I'd prefer to see the harder-to-subvert mechanisms be able to be used without cutting short the restrictions by an order of magnitude.

Comment: @Servy: the user in question was *already* creating new accounts to keep asking as many questions as they wanted to, using voting between the accounts to keep themselves from being banned again. When we find such a network of accounts, we generally clean up those accounts with anti-spam / trolling measures to stop immediate re-creation. This also applies measures that prevent new accounts from posting! The *original* account is left in place, as we did here, if the owner wants to try and redeem themselves and recover it. And yes, I personally do check back for repeat offenders.

Comment: @Servy: There is zero point in leaving the 'extra' accounts in place, because they are usually not question banned anyway, and they rarely have improved on their ability to post quality content.

Answer (score -14):

Thank you **Brad Larson** for the detailed answer.

I do not argue about penalty for users who violate rules. Punishment must be as hard as it can be. But I argue about method of tracking/detecting users who violate rules. **I have no other account, I have never asked anyone for up-voting, or any thing else of this sort**. Clearly, I am the victim here. I do **question** SO's methods.

> Your account came to our attention because there was clear evidence
>   you were using a sock puppet to vote for it...... ....they found that
>   your account here was one of at least a couple accounts that you had
>   created to evade system-imposed question asking limits.

That is clearly a misunderstanding or some **fault at SO end**. SO must investigate this.

> You can contact the company directly and see if they'll go through the
>   effort of restoring your posts to this account

I have not done anything wrong, I will not beg SO for something I haven't done. I will delete my rest of stackexchnage accounts and never use it again. I do not trust SO anymore.

**I hope this doesn't happen to any other user again.**

Comment: Sooooo....you did nothing wrong, but you'll delete all your other accounts in...protest?  Somehow, your protestations don't really sound believable.

Comment: Technically someone with the same IP address as yours can imitate to be you and upvote your posts. How can SO know that's someone else and not you?

Comment: Sure. Instead of proving your innocence or even trying to, play the offended victim and just 'give up'. If that doesn't look like an admission of guilt... I dunno what does.

Answer (score -15):

While I think a penalty for vote fraud is warranted, I believe I stand with others here in saying that your posts don't seem that bad at all. I think restoration of your posts is reasonable, with any/all ill-gotten rep/upvotes removed. Could the mods and/or Community Team accomplish this?

This is, of course subject to their willingness to have you back on the site, which, considering that you *were* able to get back by just showing back up, seems reasonable to assume.

Comment: "This is, of course subject to their willingness to have you back on the site, which, considering that you were able to get back by just showing back up, seems reasonable to assume." The account was deleted because they kept creating new accounts to subvert more temporary bans and/or other restrictions.  That doesn't seem like a reasonable thing to assume *at all*.

Comment: While I understand your feelings, starting to make these exceptions because "you contributed a lot in the past" doesn't have a nice ring to it. Even more, the OP didn't even say the truth when posting this question, so it doesn't seem we are talking about a particularly repentant user,

Comment: And I trust that the moderators and SO employees that had access to the evidence did weight everything into account when deciding the harshness of the penalty.

Comment: *I think restoration of your posts is reasonable* The posts all still exist, they're just not associated with the user's new account.

Comment: @BSMP you mean 'just not associated with any of the user's new accounts'